# Pytest Not Discovering Tests in Specified Paths with pyproject.toml Configuration

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, pyproject.toml

I'm currently working on a Python project and using pytest for testing. I have structured my project to include tests in separate directories, and I'm trying to use a `pyproject.toml` file to specify the paths where pytest should discover the test files. However, it seems like pytest is not recognizing some of the paths specified in the `pyproject.toml` file.

Here is what my `pyproject.toml` file looks like:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_paths = ["src", "tests", "tests/Google-Calendar", "tests/Reclaim", "tests/Todoist"]
```

I expected pytest to discover and run tests in all the specified directories, but it's not running the tests in `"tests/Google-Calendar"`, `"tests/Reclaim"`, and `"tests/Todoist"`. When I run `pytest` all the tests run fine however I want to run them separately by doing `pytest filename` but instead I can only do `pytest (absolute path to file)`.

Things I've tried:

1. Checked that the paths are correct and the directories exist.
2. Ensured that the test files follow the pytest naming conventions (`test_*.py` or `*_test.py`).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide some insight into what might be going wrong and how to fix it?